# Autocomplete for more than one fields shows same options in all the fields

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to angular and am trying to use angular material. To be very specific, I am using `autocomplete` feature of angular material forms.

I need to have two input dropdown fields with option to search. I have followed the example given on the official site, but it only works for a single field. If I have 2 fields, I get the same options in both the fields. 
Here is the link to my code:

[Link to my code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5eemv4)

It would be great if someone could have a look at it and let me know where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are referencing `auto` twice. Change one of em, for example, notice `auto1`

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick name" aria-label="Name" matInput [formControl]="namesControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto1">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto1="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredNames | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Here's a fork of your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5eemv4-8xkawh)

Comment: Thanks, I thought auto was some property which cannot be changed. There was not much explanation in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the exporting of matAutocomplete="auto" twice is occurring.  A quick fix is to change one to group and the other to singular:

```
<form class="example-form">
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="autoGroup">
    <mat-autocomplete #autoGroup="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>

<br>
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick name" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="namesControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredNames | async" [value]="option">
            {{option}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who like me struggled with this while using the same "options":
The accepted answer helped me figure this out. I was using the same Control and had to change them as well.

My code:

```js
  myControl = new FormControl<string | Stop>('');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptionsStart = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        const name = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name;
        return name ? this._filterStart(name as string) : this.optionsStart.slice(0, 10);
      })
    );
    this.filteredOptionsStop = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        const name = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name;
        return name ? this._filterStop(name as string) : this.optionsStop.slice(0, 10);
      })
    );
  }
```

The changed code:

```js
  myControl = new FormControl<string | Stop>('');
  myControl2 = new FormControl<string | Stop>('');

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptionsStart = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        const name = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name;
        return name ? this._filterStart(name as string) : this.optionsStart.slice(0, 10);
      })
    );
    this.filteredOptionsStop = this.myControl2.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => {
        const name = typeof value === 'string' ? value : value?.name;
        return name ? this._filterStop(name as string) : this.optionsStop.slice(0, 10);
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I faced the same issue, set different matAutocomplete property.

**Should be unique** -

- In ***Input***  ===> [matAutocomplete]="skill_auto" ,
- In ***mat-autocomplete*** ===> #skill_auto="matAutocomplete"

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select Skill</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one skill"
           aria-label="text"
           matInput
           [formControl]="skillControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="skill_auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #skill_auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of Skills" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Select Hobby</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one hobby"
           aria-label="text"
           matInput
           [formControl]="hobbyControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="hobby_auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #skill_auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of Hobbies" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```